# Facing Registration and Login issue in my app backend in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using the laravel admin panel for my app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.easynotes4u as the backend on my website [www.books.easynotes4u.com](http://www.books.easynotes4u.com).
Everything is fine except the registration and login forms on the Android App, which show the error "Try again later" when I try to login. When I try to register, the same error shows, but when I look at the admin panel, it shows that the user has registered successfully, but at the time of registration it was showing the error "Try again later." But the login form is not working. It is also showing the same error and users are unable to login. So, can anybody help me here with this issue?

Log File: https://prnt.sc/sJc79rNFIuXz

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Passport is not/bad installed.

the error log tell you that ***"oauth_personal_access_clients"  database table*** does'nt exist.

you can run to this to fix this problem

```
php artisan passport:install
```